# Is it OK to edit your own answer into an entirely different answer after it has been upvoted

Tags: discussion, edits, upvotes

An upvote is something given to (a particular version of) a particular answer.

Should the author of that answer have the authority to transfer those upvotes to a new answer that has essentially nothing in common with the original answer? How about if the new answer contradicts the original answer in some essential way?

Of course, the the fuzzy meaning of "essentially" could introduce edge-cases. I'm not asking where the edge is; I'm asking whether there is (or should be) an interior case at all.